# $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x^2+ax)}{x}\,dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, fresnel-integrals

I want to show that the following converges for $a\ge 0$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x^2+ax)}{x}\,dx$$

We can show that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2+ax)}{x} = a$, and with that fact it's straightforward to prove that
$$\left|\int_0^\delta\frac{\sin(x^2+ax)}{x}\,dx \right|< \infty$$
where $\delta >0$ is a constant.

However I'm having trouble showing that the function decays quickly enough as $x$ goes to infinity. I know how to prove this when taking the integral of $\sin(ax)/x$, but that $x^2$ is causing me problems.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You have a limit for $n\to 0$ of an expression that doesn't contain $n$?

Comment: Your second displayed expression: You should have the absolute values on the inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write as
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} \frac{2x+a}{2x+a} \sin(x^2+ax) dx$$
and integrate by parts with $dv = (2x+a) \sin(x^2+ax)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $dv=(2x+a)\sin{(x^2+ax)}$?

Comment: When I integrated by parts, I got $$\frac{-\cos(x^2+ax)}{x(2x+a)}\Bigr|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty \frac{4x+a}{x^2(2x+a)^2}\cos(x^2+ax)$$
The integral on the right converges, but the left term does not. But I suppose if you combined the argument I posted in my question and just use integration by parts on the integral in your post, but with the limits $\delta$ to $\infty$. Thoughts?

Comment: Also, how did you think of introducing those $2x+a$ terms to integrate by parts? Any thought process there? Or just experience?

Comment: @Kurt Indeed, subdividing the integral on as $[0,1]\cup (1\infty)$ solves that problem, as then the two evaluations will be bounded.

Comment: @Kurt Because $2x+a$ is the derivative of $x^2+ax$ inside the sine, so that way the chain rule is "accounted for"

Comment: @WillSherwood, Thanks, it's corrected.

Comment: @Kurt Adding/subtracting or multiplying/dividing by the same quantity is a common trick.We might think of trying the same method in proving the convergence of $\int_1^\infty \sin(t)/t dt$ using integration by parts. The issue is that our trig term doesn't have a nice anti-derivative. So we add the term necessary to make it nice, which turns out not to cause any problems with our procedure. Makes some sense? And yes, you need to combine your argument about what happens near zero with this.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to enforce the substitution $x\to \frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+4x}}{2}$.  Then, we have $x^2+ax\to x$ and for $a\ge 0$ we have

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x^2+ax)}{x}\,dx=\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4x}}{x\sqrt{a^2+4x}}\right)\,dx$$

Appealing to [Dirichlet's Test for improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals), we see that since for all $L$

$$\left|\int_0^L \sin(x)\,dx\right|\le 2$$

and $\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4x}}{x^2\sqrt{a^2+4x}}\ge 0$ monotonically approaches zero as $x\to \infty$, the integral of interest converges.